# How to view scheduled tasks or deadlines that are late

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In agenda view, how can I make a list of all tasks (more than 30 ongoing tasks) that are late?

That should included recurring scheduled tasks for the month, were I jumped a day. For example, had to do something 1,2,3,4, but did it 1,2,4. The list should keep track that some item was skipped.